# Connectycube Inactive / Active User

Tags: connectycube

Good afternoon, I need to control if a user who is in a 1:1 chat with ConnectiCube Javascript API is active/inactive. But I need to know the status of the person on the other side, not the local user. As if to say "they left me alone, it's better if I log out", please if someone can guide me or has had the same problem. I have both occupants stored in variables

I haven't tried anything at the moment since I don't know how to do it and in the documentation I can't find the solution or an example

Answer (score 1):

Please, check the guide on how to get/listen user's [last activity](https://developers.connectycube.com/js/messaging?id=get-last-activity). Note that, 0 seconds ago means that a user is online. 1> seconds means that the user is offline and you know when it was.